# Rectangular selection in Xcode

Tags: xcode

In Visual Studio I can alt+shift and use arrow keys to highlight a "box" of text in any text pane (ie. select a portion of a line, rather than an entire line, over multiple lines)

Is there an equivalent way to do this in Xcode?

Comment: here also you can use these keys for selecting text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try holding down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key down while selecting text - it lets you select rectangular areas.

Using the <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> **does not** work as the using <kbd>Alt</kbd> and the Arrow keys is bound to movement by default, and with the addition of <kbd>Shift</kbd> it selects the region during movement.

Comment: Ah, OK- Alt+mouse drag lets me select boxes.
It doesn't seem to work if I use the cursor keys though, unless I'm missing something?